# Model binding with a sub model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, model-binding

I have a model as follows:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the controller action:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register(int departmentId)
    {
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            var department = db.Departments.Find(departmentId);

            var registerModel = new RegisterModel {Department = department};

            return View(registerModel);
        } 
    }
```

I have departments list page. such as Foo, then I want to ass user to Foo.

```
1 . Foo - add user
```

then I have a register View.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Department.Id)


    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>

        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Now my question is how can i bind the Department to Model? with department Id? or department object?

I have access to Department, which i populate from database, then I need to pass it to View. but how do i pass it? so upon register submit, I can have access to it or id of it?

Comment: can you show your controller/actionresult where you return this view to the user?

Comment: ok i added it to the question

Comment: can you put this in your view somewhere: <p>@Model.Department.Id</p>  ? This should just show the department ID. I dont quite see what the problem is?

Comment: it does show. when i submit, i dont get back department.

Comment: are you trying to create a new department, or are you sending back an existing department to your view ?

Comment: if you have parameter less constructor for Department class then  after posting the form you can access the Id of the Department like:  model.Department.Id

Comment: I m sending back the department, trying to associate the user to the department

Comment: can you show your HttpPost suhmit controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `DepartmentId` and `DepartmentsList` to your `RegisterModel`:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }   

    // You don't really need this.
    //public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    // Create this list in your controller before sending it to the view.
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentsList { get; set; }
}
```

Populate the `DepartmentsList` in your `Register` action:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        var departments = db.Departments.Select(department => new SelectListItem 
                                                                    { 
                                                                        Value = department.Id, 
                                                                        Text = department.Name
                                                                    }).ToList();

        var registerModel = new RegisterModel { DepartmentsList = departments };
        return View(registerModel);
    }
}
```

Then you create a drop down list in your view:

```
<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Department)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartmentId, Model.DepartmentsList)
</li>
```

Then in your `HttpPost` action you accept a `RegisterModel`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel registerModel)
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        // Note: this is just an example..
        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = registerModel.UserName,
            Password = registerModel.Password,
            DepartmentId = registerModel.DepartmentId
        }

        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```